# How can I precisely control the position of the BarLegend in the DensityPlot?

Tags: plotting, legending

I generated the following plot and I would like to move the `BarLegend` to a specific position, how can I do that? I also faced another problem where in the `BarLegend` and close to the `Tick` on the blue side there is extra white space (marked by the green circle) that I could not get rid of?

```
With[{z0 = 0.1, zm = 0.1}, 
 lgnds = BarLegend[{{Red, White, Blue}, {-zm, z0}}, 
   Ticks -> {{-zm, Style[Text[-zm], 13, Black]}, {z0, 
      Style[Text[z0], 13, Black]}}, LegendMarkerSize -> 120, 
   LegendLabel -> 
    Placed[Style[ZZ, Red, FontSize -> 22], Left], {LegendLayout -> 
     "Row", Charting`TickSide -> Left}]; 
 Legended[DensityPlot[x y, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
   FrameStyle -> Black, FrameTicksStyle -> Black, 
   ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Red, White, Blue}, 
       Rescale[#, {-zm, z0}]] &), PlotPoints -> 80, PlotRange -> Full,
    FrameLabel -> {x, y}, ColorFunctionScaling -> False], 
  Placed[lgnds, {Top, Right}]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Specify the position numerically, e.g., `Placed[lgnds, {0.8, 1}]`

Comment: @BobHanlon, I tried that but  still there is a big space between the top side of the plot-frame and the BarLegend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the second argument of `Placed` in your code; that is, use

```
Placed[lgnds, {ImageScaled @ {1, 1}, {.92, .2}}]
```

[image]

Yo can also use `Placed[lgnds, {{1.04, 1}, {1, .2}}]` to get the same picture.

Comment: that is great, just one more question please, what if I use `ImageSize -> Automatic -> {150, 300}` inside the `DensityPlot`, is it possible to use the same trick?

Comment: @HD2006, the first approach does not for the case with  `ImageSize -> Automatic -> {150, 300}`. Second approach works with appropriate choice of numbers. E.g., `Placed[lgnds, {{1, .725}, {.94, .2}}]`.

Comment: it is not working with me, may you please update the answer i updated the question as well.

Comment: @HD2006, can you try `Placed[lgnds, {{1, 1}, {.94, .2}}]` and add the option `AspectRatio->Full`?

Comment: now everything is perfect. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Epilog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html) and [`Inset`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset.html)

**EDIT:** Corrected [`ImagePadding`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImagePadding.html) on right

```
With[
 {z0 = 0.1, zm = 0.1},
 DensityPlot[
  x y,
  {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
  FrameStyle -> Black,
  FrameTicksStyle -> Black,
  ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Red, White, Blue},
      Rescale[#, {-zm, z0}]] &),
  PlotPoints -> 80,
  PlotRange -> Full,
  FrameLabel -> {x, y},
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
  Epilog ->
   Inset[
    BarLegend[
     {{Red, White, Blue}, {-zm, z0}},
     Ticks -> {
       {-zm, Style[Text[-zm], 13, Black]},
       {z0, Style[Text[z0], 13, Black]}},
     LegendMarkerSize -> 120,
     LegendLabel -> Placed[
       Style[ZZ, Red, FontSize -> 22],
       Left],
     LegendLayout -> "Row",
     Charting`TickSide -> Left],
    {0.58, 1.17}],
  PlotRangeClipping -> False,
  ImagePadding ->
   {{Automatic, Scaled[0.02]}, {Automatic, Scaled[0.075]}}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've had trouble with this, so I usually `Rasterize` my graphics, then `Inset` my legend into my graphic.  It will take some tweaking, but `Inset` gives you basically unlimited control.  See below.

```
With[{z0 = 0.1, zm = 0.1},
 legend = 
  ListDensityPlot[{Range[-0.1, 0.1, 0.1], Range[-0.1, 0.1, 0.1]}, 
   DataRange -> All, ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Red, White, Blue}, 
       Rescale[#, {-zm, z0}]] &), PlotRange -> Full, 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, AspectRatio -> 1/10, 
   FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {None, {{1, Style[Text[-zm], 13, Black]}, 
{3, Style[Text[z0], 13, Black]}}}}, PlotRangePadding -> None];
 
 plot = Rasterize@
   DensityPlot[x y, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, FrameStyle -> Black, 
FrameTicksStyle -> Black, ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Red, White, Blue}, 
Rescale[#, {-zm, z0}]] &), PlotPoints -> 80, FrameLabel -> {x, y}, 
ColorFunctionScaling -> False,PlotLabel -> Style["ZZ", Red, FontSize -> 22]];
 
 Show[
  plot,
  Graphics@{Inset[legend, Scaled@{0.96, 0.93}, Scaled@{1, 1}, 125]},
  PlotRange -> {{-15, 375}, {-15, 400}}]
 ]
```

[image: using Inset to add a legend to graphics object]

Comment: why did you remove `LegendLabel -> Placed[Style[ZZ, Red, FontSize -> 22], Left]`?

Comment: It was an accident when I was cutting and pasting your code lol.  I added it back with PlotLabel, I'm not positive where you want it placed but you can use Inset here as well.