# How can we keep the plot range clipped while PlotRangeClipping->False?

Tags: plotting, legending, rasterize

Adding a label outside the frame at a specific position requires setting `PlotRangeClipping -> False` and this allows the plot to be outside the frame even when  `PlotRange` is specified. Such a question has been asked many times and here are some related ones [1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/245392/how-can-i-switch-off-plotrangeclipping-from-one-side-of-the-plot), [2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/267958/plotrangeclipping-is-not-working-correctly-with-listlineplot), [3](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230109/how-can-i-precisely-control-the-position-of-the-barlegend-in-the-densityplot), [4](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/276607/place-graphics-outside-plotrange-without-using-plotrangeclipping-set-to-false), [5](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/251333/epilog-outside-the-plotting-area?noredirect=1&lq=1), [6](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/236630/how-to-display-label-text-outside-plot-range-and-enable-plotrangeclipping), and [7](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/262608/how-can-i-clip-curves-properly-in-plot-and-listlineplot/262632#262632) and even when `PlotRangeClipping -> True` clipping is not perfect see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29797/plotrangeclipping-not-working-correctly-with-small-imagesize-and-pdf-export). Of course, there are different solutions as you will find in the answers to the mentioned questions but there is no general that depends only on `PlotRange`. For example,

I want to use `PlotRangeClipping -> False` with  `ImagePadding -> 80` to add arbitrary legends on the plot

```
plot=Plot[2 Sin[x], {x, -20, 20}, PlotRange -> {{-15, 16}, {-1, 1}}, 
 Frame -> True, PlotRangePadding -> None, PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
 PlotStyle -> Red, ImagePadding -> 80, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 ImageSize -> 300, 
 Epilog -> {Inset[Style["A", Green], {0, 1.3}], 
   Inset[Style["B", Green], {19, 0}]}]
```

[image]

Now I want t exclude the curves outside the `PlotRange`. I found a very nice [code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/71870/rasterized-density-plot-with-vector-axes/208988#208988) on this platform that does the job elegantly but with `Rasterize` the curve. How can I modify it to keep the plot range clipping without doing the `Rasterize` (i.e. when exporting as pdf I need the curve in vector style)?

Here is the code

ClearAll[rasterizeBackground]

```
Options[rasterizeBackground] = {"TransparentBackground" -> False, 
   Antialiasing -> False};
rasterizeBackground[g_Graphics, rs_Integer : 3000, OptionsPattern[]] :=
  Module[{raster, plotrange, rect}, {raster, plotrange} = 
   Reap[First@
     Rasterize[
      Show[g, Epilog -> {}, Prolog -> {}, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
       ImagePadding -> 0, ImageMargins -> 0, PlotLabel -> None, 
       FrameTicks -> None, Frame -> None, Axes -> None, Ticks -> None,
        PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
       Antialiasing -> OptionValue[Antialiasing], 
       GridLines -> {Function[Sow[{##}, "X"]; None], 
         Function[Sow[{##}, "Y"]; None]}], "Graphics", 
      ImageSize -> rs, 
      Background -> 
       Replace[OptionValue["TransparentBackground"], {True -> None, 
         False -> Automatic}]], _, #1 -> #2[[1]] &];
  rect = Transpose[{"X", "Y"} /. plotrange];
  Graphics[
   raster /. Raster[data_, _, rest__] :> Raster[data, rect, rest], 
   Options[g]]]

rasterizeBackground[g_, rs_Integer : 3000, OptionsPattern[]] := 
 g /. gr_Graphics :> rasterizeBackground[gr, rs]
```

and this is how we can use it

```
rasterizeBackground[plot, 500]
```

[image]

**update**

According to @Demon answer, we get the desired clip but by saving it as pdf, it is still outside the frame along the x-axis.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Place Graphics outside PlotRange without using PlotRangeClipping set to False](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/276607/place-graphics-outside-plotrange-without-using-plotrangeclipping-set-to-false) Also: [Epilog outside the plotting area](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/251333/epilog-outside-the-plotting-area?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @Domen, but that will require fixing the size of the canvas for each different plot. Actually, I am aware of different ways to do that including `Canvas`  in MMA13 with `Legended`, but the size needs to be fixed each time according to the plot size and position of the legend. However, the code above requires no adjustment, we need to drop the `Rasterize` part and will be perfect and universal.

Comment: @kglr, any idea please?

Answer (score 1):

### Method 1

Use [`Overlay`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Overlay.html) with two plots, one containing your graph and the other one green labels. The curve will still hang a bit over the frame if you zoom in, but (!) this might be considered as a bug of `PlotRangeClipping` because it appears on its own, even without combining the plots.

```
opts = {PlotRange -> plotRange, Frame -> True, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
   PlotRangeClipping -> True, Background -> White, 
   PlotStyle -> {CapForm["Butt"], Red}, ClippingStyle -> None, 
   ImagePadding -> 80, AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 300};

p1 = Plot[2 Sin[x], {x, -20, 20}, Evaluate@opts];
p2 = Plot[None, {x, -20, 20}, PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
   Background -> None, 
   Epilog -> {Inset[Style["A", Green], {0, 1.3}], 
     Inset[Style["B", Green], {19, 0}]}, Evaluate@opts];

Overlay[{p1, p2}]

Framed[%]
```

[image: Plot]

### Method 2

You can also use exact $x$ range. Additionally, use `CapForm["Butt"]` to get better clipping at the edges  – however, the diagonal curves will still hang a bit over the frame, unfortunately.

```
plotRange = {{-15, 16}, {-1, 1}};

Plot[2 Sin[x], {x, plotRange[[1, 1]], plotRange[[1, 2]]}, 
 PlotRange -> plotRange, Frame -> True, PlotRangePadding -> None, 
 PlotRangeClipping -> False, Background -> White, 
 PlotStyle -> {CapForm["Butt"], Red}, ImagePadding -> 80, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 300, 
 Epilog -> {Inset[Style["A", Green], {0, 1.3}], 
   Inset[Style["B", Green], {19, 0}]}]

Framed[%]
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: That is simpler and nice! however, it is not clipped perfectly along x, can we improve that? see my updates.

Comment: @valarmorghulis, I have provided a new solution. Please, see my update.

Answer (score 0):

@Domen provided a nice workaround but still needs some work by hand for different plots, here inspired by his answer I come up with this general solution

```
clip2dplot[plot_,plotRange_] := 
 Block[{}, 
  Show[plot, 
   RegionPlot[
    RegionDifference[
     Rectangle @@ (Transpose@(1. (plotRange + {{-Norm@plotRange[[1]], 
              Norm@plotRange[[1]]}, {-Norm@plotRange[[2]] , 
              Norm@plotRange[[2]] }}))), 
     Rectangle @@ (Transpose@plotRange)], Frame -> False, 
    PlotStyle -> White, BoundaryStyle -> None]]]
```

and this is how we can use it

```
clip2dplot[
 Plot[2 Sin[x], {x, -20, 20}, PlotRange -> {{-15, 16}, {-1, 1}}, 
  Frame -> True, PlotRangePadding -> None, PlotRangeClipping -> False,
   PlotStyle -> Red, ImagePadding -> 80, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  ImageSize -> 300, 
  Epilog -> {Inset[Style["A", Green], {0, 1.3}], 
    Inset[Style["B", Green], {19, 0}]}], 1. {{-15, 16}, {-1, 1}}]
```

[image]

It would be nice if one can help and let `clip2dplot` read the `PlotRange` directly from the plot without putting it by hand, just as in the `rasterizeBackground` code mentioned in the question.

Comment: @kglr, any idea how to read PlotRange directly?