# How to put a dot in front of a plot created with listcontourplot?

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, legending

I would like to put a large round dot at `(x,y)=(0,1)` in front of a plot constructed with the `ListContourPlot` function. I have made some attempts, but it proved to be unsuccessful. This is one of them, which shows the dot, but does not exhbit the axes:

```
data = Table[Sin[x] + Sin[y], {x, 0, 2 Pi, 0.2}, {y, 0, 2 Pi, 0.2}];
foregroundData = {{0, 1}};
plot = ListContourPlot[data];
foregroundPlot = 
  Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Red, Point[foregroundData]}];
Show[foregroundPlot, plot]
```

Could you please help me how to show both the axes and the dot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Show[plot, foregroundPlot, PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
Show[foregroundPlot, plot, PlotRangeClipping -> False, Options[plot]]
```

[image]

**Note:** Default setting for the option `PlotRangeClipping` is `True` for `ListContourPlot`:

```
Options[ListContourPlot, PlotRangeClipping]
```

> ```
> {PlotRangeClipping -> True}
> ```

You can also use `PlotRange -> All` in `Show[...]` to have the dot inside the frame:

```
Show[plot, foregroundPlot, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for posting this answer! It helped a lot!

Comment: @TobiR, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Comment: A minor question related to this one. In my real problem, `PlotRangeClipping -> False` causes that the part of the plot outside the coordinate limits also appears on the figure, which I'd like to avoid. Do you have a solution which avoids plotting data outside the ranges specified? Is this problem connected to `PlotRangeClipping -> False`  or it is induced by something else?

Comment: See if  [this Q/A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/281975/125) and the links there give what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I could not apply those things, because I could not position the red dot correctly.